# blockmodel: convert png to schematic

Tags: python, python-2.7

In blockmodel, how can I convert a png to a schematic? It's probably very simple, but I can't find an example.

I have tried looking for a `to_schematic` method or something like that, but I could not find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such method. You can do this though:

```
with open(data_path("ref/block.png"), "rb") as f:
    as_png = f.read()
bm = BlockModel.from_png(as_png)
with open("my_schematic.schematic", "wb") as f:
    f.write(bm.schematic)
```